# PyQGIS 'str' object has no attribute 'fields'

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, string, delete

I'm trying to write my first Python script from template in QGIS. I want to delete all fields except specific ones. Therefore I create a list to fill it with all the field names except the specific ones. Then I use this list to delete the fields.

But I always get the error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'fields' in Line 120

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
*   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
"""

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsField,
                       QgsFields,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
       
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the algorithm name, used for identifying the algorithm. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The name should be unique within each provider. Names should contain
        lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'delete'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name, which should be used for any
        user-visible display of the algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('delete')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs to. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The group id should be unique within each provider. Group id should
        contain lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short helper string for the algorithm. This string
        should provide a basic description about what the algorithm does and the
        parameters and outputs associated with it..
        """
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
 
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )


        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """

        # Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
        # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
        # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )
        
        
        #field to keep
        fieldnames = ['pers']
       
        #delete fields
        field_delete = []
        for field in self.INPUT.fields():
            if field.name() not in fieldnames:
                field_delete.append(field.name())
      
        

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )
        

        alg_params = {
            'COLUMN': field_delete,
            'INPUT': parameters['INPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['OUTPUT']
        }
        processing.run('qgis:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)




        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

Comment: Your error appears in the line 120: `for field in self.INPUT.fields():`. If you are accessing layer fields names it might be done via `layer.fields().names()` or via `layer.dataProvider()` which includes the method that you need `.fields()` e.i. `field_names = [field.name() for field in prov.fields()]`.

Comment: What about `for field in source.fields():`?

Comment: if you are coding with Python3, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is not anymore useful !

Comment: Thank you so much; `for field in source.fields():` worked perfectly

Comment: @BenW I think you you should put your comment as an answer